# Tracking stopped players and connecting them so they can interact

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, socket.io

This file handles the player "stopping" in space, trying to find whoever is ahead or behind (also stopped) and joining everyone into each others stopping -rooms. I'm not too sure about the whole "each others rooms" - but I can't think of a sane way to have these *N* players sit in the same room that's created at different points. (I'm afraid I'll end up having to loop thousands of rooms trying to find the Nth one where *Y*th player is supposed to be at.)

```
import {Instance} from '../load-instances';

class ToggleWalking {
    constructor(throttledSocket, socketServer) {

        throttledSocket.on('toggle-walking', () => {
            Instance.playerList.getPlayer(throttledSocket.PlayerIndex).toggleWalkingStatus();
            throttledSocket.emit('walking-status', Instance.playerList.getPlayerInfo(throttledSocket.PlayerIndex).isWalking);

            if (!Instance.playerList.getPlayerInfo(throttledSocket.PlayerIndex).isWalking) {
                let socketClientInfo = Instance.playerList.getPlayerInfo(throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                let playersAround = Instance.MapInstance.getPlayersWithin(socketClientInfo.position);
                let connectedIds = Object.keys(socketServer.of('/').connected);
                throttledSocket.join('player-stop-' + throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                playersAround.forEach(playerInfo => {
                    if (connectedIds.indexOf(playerInfo.connectionId) > -1) {
                        socketServer.getSocketById(playerInfo.connectionId).join('player-stop-' + throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                        throttledSocket.join('player-stop-' + playerInfo.index);
                        throttledSocket.emit('player-near', playerInfo);
                        socketServer.to(playerInfo.connectionId).emit('player-near', socketClientInfo);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                throttledSocket.leave('player-stop-' + throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                let socketsAroundMe = socketServer.getRoom('player-stop-' + throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                for (let socketClientId in socketsAroundMe) {
                    socketServer.getSocketById(socketClientId).leave('player-stop-' + throttledSocket.PlayerIndex);
                    throttledSocket.leave('player-stop-' + socketClientId);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

module.exports = {
    ioEvent: ToggleWalking,
    needsServer: true,
    name: 'toggle-walking',
    description: 'toggles player walking status'
};
```

`throttledSocket` is a normal `socket` from [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/), `socketServer` is the actual `io` which has these two helpers attached.

```
socketServer.getSocketById = id => socketServer.of('/').connected[id];
socketServer.getRoom = roomName => socketServer.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName];
```

Comment: Whether the code needs documentation or not is not a good question for CR.

Comment: @t3chb0t I think I managed to make this a two-parter -- should I just edit the first part out ?

Comment: The title of the question should describe the pupose of the code, what it does. Documenting or not is pretty philosophical and probably better suited for Software Engineering.

Comment: @t3chb0t You da man :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, looks good for your first post, hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Interfaces need comments which describe the contract that the implementer has to fulfill. (don't know if JS has that) In all other cases when you feel you have to comment *what* the code does **find better names** for the identifiers. But there are some rare cases when you should add comments and this is when you have to explain **why** *the code is the way it is*, eg. if it does something  in a "weired" way...